# acro long format for plural acronyms

Tags: acronyms, acro

I'm using the acro package to organize my acronyms. I want to highlight newly introduced acronys by printing the first long form in bold font. However, if the newly introduced acronym is introduced as a plural form, only the name itself is bold, but not the plural "s".

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareAcronym{CD}{
        short = CD ,
        long = Compact Disc ,
        long-format = \textbf
}

\begin{document}
\acp{CD}
\end{document}
```

The result is **Compact Disc**s (CDs) instead of **Compact Discs** (CDs).

Comment: The expected behaior should have a bold s. Did you file a bug report or suggest it tot the package maintainer?

Comment: I'm unsure that this is a straight-out bug (if it were, it should be reported directly to https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues). For `long-format=\textbf` the s probably should be typeset bold, but (as with the example in the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) documentation) using `long-format=\scshape` it's likely that the s should be typeset normally rather than as small caps.  Probably the addition of some `plural-format` key to the package is necessary.

Comment: I haven't filed a bug report yet, but will do so. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

As of [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) v2.8 the `format-include-endings` key can be used in `\acsetup` to include the endings in all `short-format`/`long-format` commands.  This cannot currently be applied on an acronym by acronym basis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{format-include-endings}

\DeclareAcronym{CD}{
        short = CD ,
        long = Compact Disc,
        long-format = \textbf,
}

\begin{document}
\acp{CD}
\end{document}
```

Prior to 2.8, or to selectively include endings in the format of certain acronyms only, this can be bodged by (ab)using the `long-plural` key which expects text only, to be appended to the long form to give the plural form, thus this may well not work perfectly or cease to work without warning.  This can be done as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{CD}{
        short = CD ,
        long = Compact Disc,
        long-format = \textbf,
        long-plural = \textbf{s},
}

\begin{document}
\acp{CD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There actually is the (apparently undocumented) option `format-include-endings` – it is, however, buggy and doesn't work :(

Comment: @clemens ah, acro is so thoroughly documented I'm surprised by undocumented features. Do you want me to add something in the answer or just leave it until you can add a better answer?

Comment: Maybe wait until I update acro. The option is useless until then

Comment: I just uploaded v2.8 to CTAN with the fix: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/99/

Comment: @clemens am I right in saying it cannot currently be used in `\DeclareAcronym` so cannot be selectively applied to acronyms yet?

Comment: that is correct. And I am not sure that I will actually add some endings-format-variable. Before this question it didn't ever seem necessary…

Comment: Answer updated.  Ideally I think it should be possible to use `format-include-endings` on an acronym by acronym basis. Using both `\textit` and `\textbf` I would personally want the endings upright and bold respectively.